# routing table configured with "ip route" part of the "iptables"?

Tags: iptables, ip, routing, netfilter

This question is frequent and has already a lot of answers, but I still don't get it. Is the routing configured with "ip route add .." part of the iptables flow? Is the "routing decision" like in the following picture the routing table configured with "ip route"?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't claim to know the source code for Linux kernel networking and Netfilter, but here's how I understand it.

**Is the routing configured with "ip route add .." part of the iptables flow?**
The short answer is yes.  See below for a longer answer.

**Is the "routing decision" like in the following picture the routing table configured with "ip route"?**
The short answer is yes.  See below for a longer answer.

I consider "iptables" to be a command that configures the Netfilter and its hooks, so I'll talk about Netfilter instead of iptables.

The routing configured with "ip route add" goes into the kernel network routing table(s), and the "routing decision" from your diagram uses the kernel network routing tables.  If you look at the diagram at the following [link](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/37/Netfilter-packet-flow.svg), you'll find a more detailed version of the diagram that you posted.  As in your diagram, the "routing decision" appears in the flow, and therefore seems to be part of the Netfilter flow.  However, if you want to get technical, you might notice that according to the colour coding in the legend, the "routing decision" is actually part of the "Other Networking" and not actually part of the NF (Netfilter).  I'll let you decide if you still consider it part of the "flow".

Note there is more in the kernel network routing tables than just what was added by "ip route add", such as local routes created automatically when interfaces are configured.  A `ip route show table all` may show you some of these additional routes.

I believe that the "routing decision" is related to the routing answer you get from the `ip route get` command.  Assuming that you use the appropriate values for the command's parameters (based on where you are in the NF flow since some network values may have changed (e.g. destination address changed by a DNAT entry)).

> ```
>    ip route get ROUTE_GET_FLAGS ADDRESS [ from ADDRESS iif STRING  ] [ oif
>            STRING ] [ mark MARK ] [ tos TOS ] [ vrf NAME ] [ ipproto PRO‐
>            TOCOL ] [ sport NUMBER ] [ dport NUMBER ]
> ```

Note that network namespaces can influence what kernel networking tables are used and what Netfilter rules are traversed.

Comment: Thank you, it gave me already good grounding in this question. Although I have a feeling so deeper it goes so more and overwhelming it gets. Is there some good interactive tutorials to get fingers on but guided?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of any good interactive tutorials on this subject.

Comment: One more question. Are all routing decision blocks from my and your picture dependent on that "other networking" that can be configured with ip route? or this are different? which are which? Where can I read more about this bridge between this "two worlds"?

Comment: My understanding is that, from the point of view of the diagrams, "other networking" = the regular networking done by the kernel but not including the NetFilter hooks that the kernel calls.  So I would assume that all routing entries that are configured via "ip route add" go into the "other networking" (i.e. general kernel networking).

Comment: I have a question: In this picture, why there is no Netfilter hook after Local Process and before Routing Decision? So there is no way to config an application's outbound traffic before routing?

Comment: @chansey, are you referring to the diagram in the original question or the diagram from the link in my answer?  The diagram from the link in my answer is more detailed and shows a number of hooks before the "reroute check".  If you needed to modify the packet before the first "routing decision" then I suppose you could mess around with the network libraries and system calls.

Comment: @DericS Sorry for replying late. I mean the diagram in the original question, but I think the diagram from your link is similar (see the arrow from "local process" to "routing decision" in your diagram). For example, if I want to modify mark of a local process' outbound packets before the "routing decision", there is no way to do in NetFilter?